# Get list of bases in an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you get a list of all the bases utilized by an object in it's creation? For instance:

```
class MixinA(object):
    pass

class MixinB(object):
    pass

class mixedClass(MixinB, MixinA, object):
    pass

my_object = mixedClass()
bases_used = my_object.???   # Is there a property that contains a list of [MixinA, MixinB, object]?
```

I'm looking to somehow extract what the bases of an *object* are, primarily because I'm actually building the object's class dynamically but I want to report on what mixins were used in certain error cases.

Comment: So the *Method Resolution Order*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the bases from the `__class__`

```
bases_used = my_object.__class__.__bases__

print(bases_used)
(<class '__main__.MixinB'>, <class '__main__.MixinA'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Answer (score 2):

see [inspect.getmro](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro), or [inspect.getclasstree](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclasstree):

```
>>> inspect.getmro(type(my_object))
(<class '__main__.mixedClass'>, <class '__main__.MixinB'>, <class '__main__.MixinA'>, <class 'object'>)
```

alternatively, [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__)

```
>>> type(my_object).__bases__
(<class '__main__.MixinB'>, <class '__main__.MixinA'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: I found `inspect.getmro` but didn't make the connection with `type()`. Thanks!